# Snake Game: wrong positioning of snake segments

Tags: java

I'm writing snake game, so I've made a `SnakeLogic` class that represents the logical model of the snake.

The implementation is the following: the snake consist of segments, each segment holds its start location, its length and direction of movement. This is the full code of the `Segment` class (inner class of `SnakeLogic`):

```
protected class Segment{

    public Point location;
    public SnakeDirection dir;
    public int length;

    public Segment(Point l, SnakeDirection dir,int length){
        location=l;
        this.dir=dir;
        this.length=length;
    }

}
```

Segments are held with a `LinkedList`:

```
private LinkedList<Segment> nodes;
```

When the direction is changed, the new segment is added at the beginning of `LinkedList`:

```
public void setDirection(SnakeDirection dir){
    //gets location and direction of first segment
    Point head = nodes.getFirst().location;
    SnakeDirection currentDir = nodes.getFirst().dir;
    //if direction isn't changed, return
    if (currentDir == dir) return;
    //ignores directions that are opposite to current one.
    switch(currentDir){
        case LEFT:
            if (dir==SnakeDirection.RIGHT) return;
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            if (dir==SnakeDirection.LEFT) return;
            break;
        case UP:
            if (dir==SnakeDirection.DOWN) return;
            break;
        case DOWN:
            if (dir==SnakeDirection.UP) return;
            break;
    }
    //adds new segment with 0 length,current first segment's location 
    //and given direction
    nodes.addFirst(new Segment(head,dir,0));
}
```

The method `Next()` calculates movement of the snake. Depending on the direction of movement, the location of first segment is changed; if the snake consists of more than 1 segment, then the length of the first segment increases by the given value (`stepSize`) and the length of the last one is decreases by this value. If the length of last segment becomes <=0, then the last segment is removed (if length is less than zero then remainder is substracted from the current last segment).

```
public void Next() {
    SnakeDirection headDir = nodes.getFirst().dir;

    switch(headDir){
        case LEFT:
            nodes.getFirst().location.x-=stepSize;
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            nodes.getFirst().location.x+=stepSize;
            break;
        case UP:
            nodes.getFirst().location.y-=stepSize;
            break;
        case DOWN:
            nodes.getFirst().location.y+=stepSize;
            break;
    }

    if (nodes.size()>1){

        nodes.getFirst().length+=stepSize;
        int newLength = nodes.getLast().length-stepSize;

        if (newLength<=0){
            nodes.removeLast();
            nodes.getLast().length-=newLength;
        }
        else{
            nodes.getLast().length=newLength;
        }

    }
}
```

When I started to test it, I found out that for some strange reason the locations of the other segments changes with the first segment's location, when they must stay in place. It looks like this:

[image]

Everything else seems to work fine. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: It would be much easier to answer if you posted [mvce]. What are the initial values of `LinkedList<Segment> nodes` ?

Comment: You would need to post a [mcve]. Why keep the direction for each segment? Won't each segment occupy the location of the segment after it on each movement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a new Segment you pass the location object of the first segment, instead of a COPY of that location. So all of your segment objects share the VERY SAME location object. If you modify it inside the new segment it will be also modified in ALL the other segments, because it's the same object.
(When you pass an object then you pass the reference of the object, not the valuu of the object.)
So instead of this line:

```
Point head = nodes.getFirst().location;
```

use this:

```
Point head = new Point(nodes.getFirst().location);
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you. By the way, using Points instead xs and ys was a very bad decision, i cannot explain why I've done this.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to know where your problem is without an MCVE, but the design seems overly complex. Instead of working with segments, work with points.

Assuming your point looks like

```
class Point {
    int x, y;
    // getters/setters if you want
}
```

Then the snake is represented by a list of points and a direction:

```
class Snake {
    List<Point> body = new LinkedList<>();
    Point head; // easier to separate the head, but you can do with including it in the list
    Direction dir;
}
```

to which you can add the `next()` method to calculate the representation of the snake:

```
void next() {
    int temp1x = head.x;
    int temp1y = head.y;
    switch(dir) {
        case LEFT:
            head.x -= stepSize;
            break;
        //...
    }
    int temp2x, temp2y;
    for (Point point : points) {
        temp2x = point.x;
        temp2y = point.y;
        point.x = temp1x;
        point.y = temp1y;
        temp1x = temp2x;
        temp1y = temp2y;
    }
}
```

I'll leave it to you to simplify the implementation (you can work with `Point` instead of separate x and y `int`s if you expand the `Point` class to allow it).

**Notes:**

- `LinkedList` is indeed a good choice for the list implementation.
- Method names start with a lowercase (`next` instead of `Next`).

Comment: Thank for your advices, I will work on it, it's definitely needs to be simplified.

My first idea was to store only coordinates for start and end of segment, but then I thought that it will be difficult to find out in which direction last segment is moving and what to do with it's end coordinates. That's reason why i decided to store direction for  each segment. 
Well, now I see that it's  easy as a pie.

By the way, can anyone give me a piece of advice on how not to complicate my code.
It seems to be my problem, I frequently use not very obvious solutions. :)

Comment: @MadScientist "*can anyone give me a piece of advice on how not to complicate my code*" Mostly experience. Try to think from a theoretical point of view - what are the basic buildings blocks, what data they represent and how, and what they need to do. In the classic Snake game, a snake is made of adjacent squares/points, so represent it as such. Note that the list of points in the code doesn't enforce adjacency even, so you can have a disjoint snake if you want, but it doesn't interfere.